# R httr - $ operator error after ~100 GET requests

Tags: r, get, spotify, httr

I'm playing around with the httr package at home, trying to pull back information about my Spotify library using their API. I'm running into a peculiar problem on which I couldn't find any help online, and I was hoping someone more well versed could point me towards a solution.

I have a list of my Spotify library songs' URI's, and all I'm trying to do is to retrieve the artists' names.

```
 getArtistName <- function(x){
    GET(paste('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/', x, "/", sep="")) %>% 
    content %>%
    .$artists %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .$name
 }

 songs.df$Artist <- sapply(songs.df$ID, getArtistName)
```

However, after some time I get the error

```
Error in .$artists : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Which is odd, because if I use GET individually, it works fine, i.e.

```
 GET(paste('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/', songs.df$ID[1], "/", sep="")) %>% 
    content %>%
    .$artists %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .$name

[1] "Viktor Vaughn"
```

Then I decided to use a for loop to apply the function to each ID individually, in case there was a faulty one,

```
for(i in 1:nrow(songs.df)){
  songs.df$Artist[i] <- GET(paste('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/', songs.df$ID[i], "/", sep="")) %>% 
    content %>%
    .$artists %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .$name
}
```

but after the 100th iteration, I get the same $ operator error.

```
Error in .$artists : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> i
[1] 101
```

But when I tried to get the artist name for `songs.df$ID[101]` outside of the loop, it worked!

So I started the loop from 101 again, and it pulls back the 101th ID fine, but stops after another 50-100 loops. This keeps going on and on, I'm getting the $ operator error every 50-100 attempt, at which point I start the loop again from that `i`, and then it stops again, etc.

Has anyone encountered anything similar before? Is there a limitation on the number of `GET`s you can do at once?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#rate-limiting

Comment: Well, that was simple enough, thank you!